TypeScript: "Type is generic and can only be indexed for reading. (2862)"
Imagine this example JS function that I'd like to add types for:
const remap = (obj) => {
  const mapped = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    mapped[key] = !!key;
  });

  return mapped;
};


I'm trying to add types via a generic (in this TS playground), but I keep hitting this error:
Type 'Mapped<T>' is generic and can only be indexed for reading.(2862)

type Mapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: boolean;
};

const remap = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: T
) => {
  const mapped: Mapped<T> = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    mapped[key] = !!key; // Type 'Mapped<T>' is generic and can only be indexed for reading.(2862)
  });

  return mapped;
};

I'd like to understand why TS won't allow me to write to this object of a generic type, and whether there's some other way around it. I'm expecting TS to understand the type of mapped and allow me to write to it, but it will not.
Is the only way to make TS accept this to use as when returning?
const remapWithAs = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: T
) => {
  const mapped: Record<string, boolean> = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    mapped[key] = !!key;
  });

  return mapped as Mapped<T>; // Is this my only option?
};


Yes I think you need an assertion of some sort to make this work. If you want to, you can skip the intermediate step of having mapped: https://tsplay.dev/wXL21w

Your problem is that Object.keys() returns string[] and not (keyof T)[]. See this question/answer. If you assert that it returns a keyof, as shown in this playground link, then it will work. So an assertion is necessary, but only to avoid the issue that Object.keys() might return more keys than TS knows about. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or link a suitable duplicate). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz that answers my question and explains the why behind it. Thank you! It totally makes sense why it's happening, but I was thrown by the error message; it made me think there was nothing I could do to let me to index it. (Was also thrown by the lack of any references to this error!) Based on the solution, I guess I would've expected a message more like expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type Mapped<T>.

The underlying reason for the error is that Object.keys(x) is declared in the TS library to return string[] and not something like (keyof typeof x)[]. This is intentional; see Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?.  So when you index mapped[key], you are doing so with a key of string and not necessarily with a key of Mapped<T>.  And therefore, it is technically unsafe to write a boolean to it, because maybe you're writing to a key that Mapped<T> doesn't know about, and you can't be sure that key would accept a boolean.  You'd need to either make Mapped<T> just be {[k: string]: boolean} (which means T is unnecessary) or you need to assert that what you're doing is safe.
Note that TypeScript will let you read a boolean from mapped[key], even though this is technically unsafe also:
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  const test = mapped[key]; // boolean | undefined
});

Such is TypeScript.  Anyway, that's why you get the error message that Mapped<T> can only be indexed (with string) for reading.  It used to just say that you couldn't index Mapped<T> with string at all, but since that's patently untrue as shown above, they changed the error message to the new wording.  See microsoft/TypeScript#47357 for more information.

Anyway, the normal approach with asserting is to say that you're confident that Object.keys(obj) will return (keyof T)[], despite TypeScript's reservations that maybe other keys will be present.  If you do that:
const remap = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  initialState: T
) => {
  const mapped: Mapped<T> = {};
  (Object.keys(initialState) as (keyof T)[]).forEach(key => {
    mapped[key] = !!key; // okay
  });

  return mapped;
};

then it works as written. TypeScript is happy to allow that mapped[key] is of type Mapped<T>[keyof Mapped<T>] which is boolean | undefined, and therefore it will accept a boolean.
Playground link to code
